# How to convert nested callbacks to promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise

I have nested callbacks that are causing problems. I want to change to promises but I'm not exactly sure how to do it.

I have first getting an array of output

```
require('abcd').open(cnnectionString, function(er, conn) {  
    // I get list back from following query
   conn.query('select first 10 name, phone from........', function(err, result) {
       if(err) {
       } else {
           // for each name and phone I call another query
           for(i = 0; i <= result.length; i++) {
                conn.query('select address from......where name=result[i].name',  
                function(error, result1) {
                     // I call third query based on data from second query
                     conn.query('select acct from .......where ', function(err, result2) { 
                          console.log(result2)
                     })  
                })                
           })
})
```

With this approach I get all kind of bad results due to async. Please let me know  how I can change it to promises.

Comment: First step.  Lean the promise interface to your database, find examples of its use and start using it instead of the callback interface.  You will need to read some documentation and some tutorials in order to do that.  For multiple async operations in a loop, learn how to use `Promise.all()` to track multiple async operations.

Comment: I hope this video could help you a bit with promises https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2d7s3spWAzo&t=4s

Comment: You should *first* turn the three nested queries into one query: use the power of your database to produce these results in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `Promise.all()`, Please have a look at bellow and give it a try:

```
var connection;
var promises = [];
require('abcd').open(cnnectionString)
  .then(function(conn) {
    connection = conn;
    return connection.query('select first 10 name, phone from........');    
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    for (i=0; i<=result.length; i++) {
      var promise = connection.query('select address from......where name=result[i].name');      
      promises.push(promise);
    }    
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err, 'error');
  });

Promise.all(promises).then(function(result) {
  console.log(result, 'result');
});
```

Comment: It gives the result for first query for second one there is error conn not defined on line where var promises=conn.query.....

Comment: @J.Davidson Yeah I just saw it and upadated my answer please have a look, create a variable connection and used `connection = conn`. Though it would not be needed if we used `arrow-functions`

Comment: Yes I saw that after entering the comment. I have a third query that I need to take one value from result and run that should it where result is printed also will I need to push promises too or just can do with out it. Thank you for you help

Comment: Yes, all of the logic after query is ran can be done in result of all's .then method. I guess you need to keep track of all promises being returned. that's why array is needed there.

Comment: @J.Davidson I'm glad to help :)

Comment: problem is still with connection that query returns no result while when i switch around the query with conn.query it gives the result. So I think that connection or something is not working there

Comment: In second query or first ?

Comment: second one. First one is fine. It is same connection problem looks like cause query will just give blank reply while i know it should have value

Comment: is this `'select address from......where name=result[i].name'` correct query, does it gives result directly running on database ?

Comment: Yes it is correct but it just returns empty result. I will check again later and get back. thanks

Answer (score 0):

this following code can help you to understand how to change callbacks to promises in your code

```
var name = require('abcd');
name.open(connectionString)
.then(function(conn) {
    //query
   })
.then(function(other) {
   })
});
```

you can go through these links to understand promises in nodejs, there are examples also given 
https://developer.ibm.com/node/2016/08/24/promises-in-node-js-an-alternative-to-callbacks/
https://www.guru99.com/node-js-promise-generator-event.html